# Regular expression to pull the inner content from a WordPress shortcode

Tags: regex, wordpress

I have a WordPress shortcode that opens with a `[pullquote]` and ends with `[/pullquote]`. I'm trying to get whatever is inside of the opening and closing tags.

I'm new to regular expressions so I stared with a simple one that captures letters, numbers and spaces.

`\[pullquote\]([0-9a-zA-z\s]*)\[\/pullquote\]`

That works fine but doesn't account for punctuation etc. so I tried `(.*)` which was doing too much and not nearly specific enough.

**Finally I tried this**

`\[pullquote\](^(?:\[\/pullquote\])*)\[\/pullquote\]`

I'm not clear on the terminology here but essentially wanted to get anything that started with `[pullquote]` captured whatever came after that provided it wasn't `[/pullquote]` and ended with `[/pullquote]`.

At least on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) it didn't work but I assume that means I did something wrong.

**Text used on regexr**

```
[pullquote]Something[/pullquote]
[pullquote]Something else.[/pullquote]
```

How can I make this work and am I doing anything else wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: use `(.*?)` to make it a non-greedy capture. It will then stop when it first can rather than capturing everything.

Comment: Not sure that this is best solved using regex as opposed to simple string search (i.e. `strpos()`).

Comment: @MikeBrant Not sure how I'd use `strpost` to solve this. Seems to only get the first or last occurrence of a string but I may have several in a single post.

Comment: Is it possible to have a `[pullquote]` tag inside another? I mean: `[pullquote] bla bla bla [pullquote] bla bla [/pullquote][/pullquote]`

Comment: No @JorgeCampos there are no nested tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just this:

```
(\[pullquote\])(.+)(\[\/pullquote\])
```

And get only what is group 2 `$2`

See it here: https://regex101.com/r/dS8eZ0/2

The information pulled out of the link:

```
MATCH INFORMATION
"(\[pullquote\])(.+)(\[\/pullquote\])/g"
    1st Capturing group "(\[pullquote\])"
      "\[" matches the character [ literally         
      "pullquote" matches the characters pullquote literally (case sensitive)
      "\]" matches the character ] literally
    2nd Capturing group "(.+)"
     ".+" matches any character (except newline)
       "Quantifier: +" Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, 
                       giving back as needed [greedy]
    3rd Capturing group "(\[\/pullquote\])"
      "\[" matches the character [ literally
      "\/" matches the character / literally
      "pullquote" matches the characters pullquote literally (case sensitive)
      "\]" matches the character ] literally
  "g" modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: How would I add new lines to this? Because it is the post body and will often include new lines. `(.\n+)`?

Comment: @jeanpier_re adding the `gm` modifiers

Answer (score 1):

Here is rudimentary search using `strpos()` you might try something like this for performance comparison sake.

```
function extract_shortcode_content($needle, $haystack) {
    if(empty($needle) || empty($haystack || !is_string($needle) || !is_string($haystack)) {
        throw new Exception('Bad input');
    }
    // $needle is just intended to be shortcode value (i.e. 'pullquote')
    // we will build appropriate start and end tags
    $needle_trimmed = trim(trim($needle), '[]');
    $start_code = '[' . $needle_trimmed. ']';
    $end_code = '[/' . $needle_trimmed . ']';
    $start_code_length = strlen($start_code);
    $end_code_length = strlen($end_code);
    $haystack_length = strlen($haystack);
    $last_searchable_position = $haystack_length - $start_code_length - $end_code_length - 1;

    $return_array = array();

    // iterate through haystack extracting content
    $search_offset = 0;
    $continue = true;

    while($search_offset < $last_searchable_position) {
        $start_code_found = strpos($haystack, $start_code, $search_offset) {        
        if ($start_code_found === false) {
            // no match in remainder of string
            return $return_array;
        }

        // extract content
        $content_start_position = $code_found + $start_code_length;
        $end_code found = strpos($haystack, $start_code, $content_start_position);
        if ($end_code_found === false) {
            // we couldn't find close for current shortcode open tag.
            // we don't count this as a match, so let's just return matches we have
            return $return_array;
        }
        $match_length = $end_close_found - $content_start_position;
        // add content to result array
        $result_array[] = substr($haystack, $content_start_position, $match_length);
        // set new search offset position for next iteration
        $search_offset = $end_code_found + $end_code_length;
    }

    return $return_array;
}
```

Now, I am not suggesting that you should use this instead of the regex approach.  Certainly the regex approach can get the same result in a few lines of code. I am simply suggesting that this approach may perform better than regex for this use case. This may however be a micro-optimization for your use case and not be worth the extra code complexity.

I just wanted to provide an alternate suggestion to regex.